# How to apply a HOC dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to apply the HOC to every child in my custom component. But I can't solve how to implement this for dynamic wrapped component type. Let say we have:

```
function myHOC<P>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>):React.ComponentType<P> {
    return class extends React.Component<P> {
      ...
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent />;
        }



const MyHOC = myHOC(???); //It won't do!

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    ...
    render() {
        const items = this.props.children.map((child) => {
            <MyHOC /> //I want to use it something like this!
        }); 

        return ( 
            <div>
                {items}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What do I need to add?

Comment: myHOC is a noop. What does it really do? Consider updating the code. This affects how it can be used properly.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply HOC dynamically. If you want to use shared stateful logic dynamically you can think about render props pattern.